# Why should the error of a local linearization for $x$ near $a$ be small relative to $(x-a)$?

Tags: calculus

I am reading a calculus book. It says

> The fact that the graph of $f$ looks like a line as we zoom in means that not only is $E(x)$ small for $x$ near $a$, but also that $E(x)$ is small relative to $(x−a)$

where $E(x) = f(x) - f(a) - f(a)^{'}(x-a)$ is an error of the local linearization, and then introduces a theorem that $$\lim_{x\to a}{\frac{E(x)}{x-a}}=0$$
I just can't understand why $E(x)$ should be small relative to $(x-a)$. What is the need to be so if we want a function to be linear when we zoom in?

P.S. My question is not about why the theorem holds. Rather I can't understand the quoted statement above. Why relative to $(x-a)$ not other value. What is special about this relation?

Comment: The *meaning* of "small relative to $x-a$ is exactly this limit relation: the quantity vanishes in the relevant limit even when divided by $x-a$. If you don't understand the intuitive statement, then just accept the math and roll with it. This limit property is itself really just a restatement of the definition of $f'(a)$.

Comment: @Ian, I wish I could see what you can see :) For me it has no even an implicit relation to $f'(a)$.

Comment: $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)-f'(a)(x-a)}{x-a} = 0$ is equivalent to $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = f'(a)$ just by moving terms to the other side.

Comment: @Ian, thank you for you effort. Yes, I see. What should I imply next to get the answer to the question?

Comment: Basically if you replaced $f'(a)$ by some other number then $E(x)/(x-a)$ would go to some nonzero constant, which would mean that $|E(x)|$, at least near $a$, is bigger than it needs to be for a linear approximation.

Comment: @Ian, you say "bigger than it **needs** to be for a linear approximation". What is that thing which determines a boundary or what values the error must take for a linear approximation? Is there one?

Comment: OP, I think the best way is to draw a picture (indeed, lots of them). The idea is that we are controlling the error in the estimate of $f(x)$ by the error in the independent variable because otherwise we would have no grasp on it. The function is a function of $x$ (think of this dynamically), so that if the approximation in $x$ does not have any purchase on the approximation in $f(x),$ we have no guarantee that the approximation of $f(x)$ is as good as we want it. That condition controls the error in such a way as to ensure that what we want happens (as explained in the answers below).

Comment: @Allawonder as I understood this ratio $\frac{E(x)}{x-a}$ is like an error per "interval length". So theorem shows as smaller the distance (or as x is close to a) the smaller the error gets, eventually becoming 0?

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov Yes, that's alright. But your question was not about how to interpret or understand this limit, but why this particular one was chosen. Otherwise, you actually have (or rather have had) two distinct questions without knowing it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to focus on the intuition. I make no claims that my answer is rigorous.

Write $$E(x) = f(x)-f(a)-f^{\prime}(a)(x-a)\text{.}$$

$f^{\prime}(a)$ is the "slope" of $f$ at $x = a$. Make sure you understand that derivatives are just slopes. For sake of convenience, let's call this $m$.

Way back in your Pre-Calculus days, remember that the computational formula for the slope of a **linear equation** (hence why there's so much focus on linearity) is
$$m = \dfrac{y_2 -y_1}{x_2 - x_1}\text{.}$$

Now, you can think of $x$ and $a$ as corresponding to $x_2$ and $x_1$ respectively. Hence we have
$$m(x_2 - x_1) = y_2-y_1 \implies m(x-a)=y_2-y_1\text{.}$$
For a linear function $f$, $y_2$ is the $y$-value of $f$ at $x$ and $y_1$ is the $y$-value of $f$ at $a$. Hence, we have
$$m(x-a) = f(x)-f(a)$$
when $f$ is linear, but when $f$ is non-linear, this is only an approximation. So,
$$m(x-a) \approx f(x)-f(a)$$
and hence, for $x$ near $a$, we would hope that
$$E(x) \approx f(x)-f(a)-[f(x)-f(a)] = 0\text{.}$$
This explains the first claim.

I think @callculus explained the second claim sufficiently well: note that in order to even begin to compute $f^{\prime}(a)$, $f$ must be differentiable at $a$. Notice that
$$\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x \to a}\dfrac{E(x)}{x-a} &= \lim_{x \to a}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)-f^{\prime}(a)(x-a)}{x-a} \\
&= \lim\limits_{x \to a}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-\lim\limits_{x \to a}\dfrac{(x-a)f^{\prime}(a)}{x-a} \\
&=\lim\limits_{x \to a}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-f^{\prime}(a)
\end{align}$$
The limit $$\lim\limits_{x \to a}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$
must exist for $f$ to be differentiable at $a$ (this is by the **definition** of a derivative); otherwise, you wouldn't be able to compute $f^{\prime}(a)$. 
As long as $f$ is differentiable at $a$, the resulting limit above is
$$\lim\limits_{x \to a}\dfrac{E(x)}{x-a} = f^{\prime}(a)-f^{\prime}(a) = 0\text{.}$$

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: It means that $f'(a)\cdot(x-a)+f(a)$ is strictly *the* best linear approximation to $f$ close to $a$. Thus justifying that $f$ has a single slope at $a$, called $f'(a)$.

Comment: Still can't get why this relation implies "best linear approximation". Why exactly relative to $(x-a)$ not some other value?

Comment: For a general line $g(x)=mx+n$, we don't have $g(a)=f(a)$, so they are bad approximations. However, some linear functions have $g(a)=f(a)$, so they are better approximations. They may be written as $g(x)=m(x-a)+f(a)$. Now, how would we compare different values of $m$ and how good approximations those give? That's exactly by taking some small step away from $a$, and see which one is closest to the value of $f$ at that point. For very small steps, that error is roughly proportional to the step size. You want the corresponding constant of proportionality to be $0$. $x-a$ is that step size.

Answer (score 0):

A longer answer: If we had a local linear approximation for $f$ at $a$, $L_f(x) = c\,x + d$ which we can write as $f(x)=c_1(x-a) + c_0$, then any *local* approximation should be asymptotically correct as $x\to a$: $\frac{c_0}{f(a)} = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{L_f(x)}{f(x)} = 1$, or $c_0=f(a)$. Otherwise we aren't capturing the local information at any order.

On the other hand, for a local *linear* approximation to work, we'd want the linearization to be asymptotically correct as you approach $a$ as well. Since we already constrained $f\to L_f$ as $x\to a$, we want
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{L_f(x)-L_f(a)}{f(x)-f(a)} = 1.
$$
But by L'Hospital's rule (assuming continuity and differentiability of $f$ at $a$)
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{L_f(x)}{f(x)} = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{c_1(x-a)}{f(x)-f(a)} = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{c_1}{f'(x)} = \frac{c_1}{f'(a)} = 1.
$$
if and only if $c_1=f'(a)$.

Regarding the error term $E(x) = f(x) - L_f(x)$, this all implies by L'Hospital's rule again
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{E(x)}{x-a} = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x) - L_f(x)}{x-a} = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x) - L_f'(x)}{1} = f'(a) - L_f'(a) = f'(a) - c_1 = 0.
$$
In summary, if you have an asymptotically correct linear approximation to a function $f$ then the error is small relative to the linear term, or else you didn't do a good job in the first place.

Comment: Can I know what you mean by "asymptotically correct"? Just to read about it or understand a little to proceed reading your answer further.

Comment: [Usually](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis#Definition) we define a function $f$ to be asymptotically equal to another $g$ if $f/g$ approaches $1$. In the limit, intuitively, this means that $f=g$, but allows for things to grow to infinity, for example, so long as the rates are the same.

Comment: So you meant "asymptotically equal" not "asymptotically correct"? Or both are interchangeable?

Comment: I think you can switch around the terminology without issue, but sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the equation by $(x-a)$

$E(x) = f(x) - f(a) - f^{'}(a)(x-a)$

$\frac{E(x)}{x-a}=\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}-f^{'}(a)$

$\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}$ is a difference quotient. If we calculate the limit it becomes a differential quotient. And by definition we get

$$\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}=f^{'}(a)$$

$f(x)$ has to be [differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function) on its domain.

Comment: What you have said seem like mere facts to me that I already know. For whatever reason I can't assembly it and understand what I should conclude. I will really apprieciate if you can answer like "We need $E(x)$ to be smaller than $(x-a)$ because ..., otherwise something like ... would happen".

Answer (score 0):

The idea is this: We want to approximate a function $f$ (which it is possible to approximate thus) by a linear function $\ell$ near a point $a.$ Therefore, it must be the case that $f(a)$ coincides with $\ell(a).$ Furthermore, we must require that $f'(a)=\ell'(a).$ Since higher derivatives of $\ell$ vanish, there is nothing more to be gained in this direction.

Now the question is: Do these conditions suffice to give us the best $\ell$ that does the job? By definition, we have that $$\ell(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a),$$ so that $$f(x)=\ell(x)+E(x).$$ Now, whether or not $\ell$ does the job well depends on how $E(x)$ compares to the other summand in the equation $f(x)=\ell(x)+E(x).$ If you can see this, then we're not far from the goal, for the other summand is just a linear function, whose significant part is clearly the term $x-a.$ In particular, the error $E(x)$ must be smaller than the term $\ell(x)$ for the approximation to be sensible. There is simply no other quantity to compare the error to except the term $\ell(x)$ if we want our approximation to be the best linear one. This is why we require that near $a,$ the term $E(x)$ should always be dominated by $x-a$ (for clearly if this is the case then we have what we want, since $|x-a|<|\ell(x)|$), for otherwise we could extract more linear information from it, as it were, which would mean that our approximation wasn't the best possible, after all, which we do not want.